# Format duplicated message

Tags: c#, asp.net

The message I get:

> Inventory contains insufficient items for LCD Dispenser ,Inventory
>   contains insufficient items for Tower Dispenser

The message I would expect:

> Inventory contains insufficient items for LCD Dispenser,Tower
>   Dispenser

```
List<string> errors = new List<string>();
for (int index = 0; index < this.gridagree.Rows.Count; index++)
{
    int productId = Convert.ToInt32(gridagree.Rows[index].Cells[3].Text);
    string productname = gridagree.Rows[index].Cells[4].Text;
    int quantityRequested = Convert.ToInt32(gridagree.Rows[index].Cells[5].Text);
    int availableQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(s.getprodqun(productId));

    if (quantityRequested > availableQuantity)
    {
        errors.Add(string.Format("Inventory contains insufficient items for {0} ", productname));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On each iteration where an error is encountered, add only the `productname` to the `errors` array, not the whole error message.

```
List<string> errors = new List<string>();
for (int index = 0; index < this.gridagree.Rows.Count; index++)
{
    int productId = Convert.ToInt32(gridagree.Rows[index].Cells[3].Text);
    string productname = gridagree.Rows[index].Cells[4].Text;
    int quantityRequested = Convert.ToInt32(gridagree.Rows[index].Cells[5].Text);
    int availableQuantity = Convert.ToInt32(s.getprodqun(productId));

    if (quantityRequested > availableQuantity)
    {
        errors.Add(productname);
    }
}
```

Afterwards, use `string.Join` to concatenate them into one error message.

```
var errorMessage = string.Format("Inventory contains insufficient items for {0} ",
        string.Join(',', errors));
```

The first argument of `string.Join` is the separator, in this case `','`. The second argument is the array of values to concatenate (separated by the specified separator).